# Workflow end/completion date

Tags: workflow

Does SharePoint contain the date when a workflow ends?  I need to add the completion date of a workflow once the approval workflow has finish and has been approved.

Mike

Answer (score 2):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Approval Workflow

Step 2 is the new addition

Comment: I would move the Set End Date to Today right to the end of the workflow, inside the else branch, just before "Set workflow status to Approved"

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm a bit of a workflow novice.  I think I've edited it correctly.  I didn't have Approval Date as an option so I created a new date column for the document library.  I've screen grabbed the workflow, would you be able to check it?

Comment: Yep sorry, forgot to mention you would have to add a new date column to your library.

Comment: I've ran the workflow and I get this error. The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information. The workflow operation failed because the action requires the document to be checked out. –

Comment: Do I need to check out the doc as a part of the workflow?